# Print intLevel in log4j2

Tags: jdbc, log4j2, pattern-layout

You can see in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html the numerical values corresponding to built-in log4j2 logging levels, for example INFO->400. How can you refer to it in patternlayout resp. in JDBC Logger configuration?

I have an old log4j 1.x config for JDBC where it was referred as %iprio.

A workaround is to use

> level{OFF=0,FATAL=100,ERROR=200,WARN=300,INFO=400,DEBUG=500,TRACE=600,ALL=1000}

but I am not very happy about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to log the integer value of the log level instead of the name and you don't want to use the labeling feature of the `PatternLayout`'s `level` parameter.

One possible solution would be to create a [custom `Lookup`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Lookups), here is some sample code:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup;

@Plugin(name = "level", category = "Lookup")
public class LevelLookup implements StrLookup{
    /**
     * Lookup the value for the key.
     * @param key  the key to be looked up, may be null
     * @return The value for the key.
     */
    public String lookup(String key) {
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Lookup the value for the key using the data in the LogEvent.
     * @param event The current LogEvent.
     * @param key  the key to be looked up, may be null
     * @return The value associated with the key.
     */
    public String lookup(LogEvent event, String key) {
        return String.valueOf(event.getLevel().intLevel());
    }
}
```

Next, here is a sample configuration using the new lookup - note the `${level:}`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] ${level:} %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />           
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is some sample code that performs some logging:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        log.debug("This is some debug!");
        log.info("Here's some info!");
        log.error("Some erorr happened!");
    }
}
```

and finally here is the output:

```
22:49:29.438 [main] 500 example.SomeClass - This is some debug!
22:49:29.440 [main] 400 example.SomeClass - Here's some info!
22:49:29.440 [main] 200 example.SomeClass - Some erorr happened!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this works with one additinal supplement: log4j does not process the @Plugin annotation without explicitly tell him it in the packages attribut of the configuration tag: packages="example".
I should also mention that according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342950/log4j2-lookup-plugin-strlookup-to-resolve-threadname-for-routing-rollinglogf we are not allowed to use camelcased lookup name. I wanted to use ${intLevel:} but it does not work.

Comment: Glad that this works for you. Note that log4j2 should create "Serialized plugin listing files" automatically during the build [per the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html) unless you have disabled this.

Comment: Also, I'm not aware of any naming restrictions when naming a lookup other than uniqueness. When I replace the lookup name "level" with "intLevel" in my example code it works fine. Perhaps this was a bug in an older version of log4j2 as the question you linked says OP was using 2.2 and 2.3